# Why does Clone() appear to perform a deep copy?

Tags: c#

I create an ArrayList, I clone it, and add an element to the original, it does not appear to show up in the clone. Clone , according to the VS documentation, performs a shallow copy.

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
namespace WhatDoesCloneDo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList a, b;
            a = new ArrayList();
            a.Add("Chocolate");
            a.Add("Vanilla");
            a.Add("Crumb");

            b = (ArrayList) a.Clone();
            // What's in b and a?
            a.Add("Cheese");
            Console.WriteLine(a.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(b.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output

```
4
3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: It is not a deep copy, only the collection gets cloned, not its elements.  But you can't see that when you use immutable strings.  Having Clone() behave so unpredictable is one reason why List<> doesn't have it.

Comment: You don't know what the terms shallow and deep clone mean. You should go look them up.

Comment: @Will Thanks so much! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you `Clone`, you have a new object, it is not the same reference.

In your sample you add, you clone `a` a generate a new instance of `ArrayList` pointing to the reference `b`. You add a new element at `a`, which is not the same as `b`. That's the reason you have the output:

```
4
3
```

If you do something like this:

```
ArrayList b = a;
```

You are not cloning an object. It will provide the same object on both references `a` and `b`. And you will get the output:

```
4
4
```

From the [`ArrayList.Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.arraylist.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN documentation:

> A shallow copy of a collection copies only the elements of the
>   collection, whether they are reference types or value types, but it
>   does not copy the objects that the references refer to. The references
>   in the new collection point to the same objects that the references in
>   the original collection point to.

Answer (score 1):

A shallow copy is still a copy and therefor a 2nd instance of a list. Adding an item to array `a` does not add it to array `b`.

What a shallow copy means that the references *in* each array reference the same instance. A deep copy would create new instances for each item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Because a clone isn't a reference, the clones in attack of the clones weren't shallow copies of Boba Fett.

Answer (score 0):

You have a *shallow* copy (`ArrayList` items will *not be cloned*):

```
   var a = new ArrayList();

   a.Add("Chocolate");
   a.Add("Vanilla");
   a.Add("Crumb");

   var b = (ArrayList) a.Clone();

   bool deep = false;

   for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; ++i) 
     if (!object.ReferenceEquals(a[i], b[i])) {
       // If we have at least one b[i] instance 
       // which doesn't share the corresponding a[i] reference 
       // we can suspect that we perform deep copy
       deep = true;

       break;  
     }

  Console.Write(deep ? "Deep" : "Shallow");
```

Finally, let's have a llok at the `ArrayList.Clone()` *source code*:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,46e5b8aaeb6679f2

```
    // Clones this ArrayList, doing a shallow copy.  (A copy is made of all
    // Object references in the ArrayList, but the Objects pointed to 
    // are not cloned).
    public virtual Object Clone()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Object>() != null);
        ArrayList la = new ArrayList(_size);
        la._size = _size;
        la._version = _version;
        Array.Copy(_items, 0, la._items, 0, _size);
        return la;
    }
```

in order to find out that `Clone` is a *shallow copy*.

Answer (score 0):

The shallow copy is creating a copy of the object `ArrayList` with the same references as the original.

References in the collection are shared hence it is not a "deep" copy.

```
public class Food
{
    public Food(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

ArrayList a, b;
a = new ArrayList();
a.Add(new Food("Cocoa"));

b = (ArrayList)a.Clone();

// a, b now have "Chocolate" instead of "Cocoa"
((Food)b[0]).Name = "Chocolate";

Console.WriteLine(a[0]); // Prints "Chocolate"
Console.WriteLine(b[0]); // Prints "Chocolate"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be mistaken about the difference between shallow and deep copies.

In a shallow copy, a new object will be created and all of the values of the members from the original will be copied over.

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList(); // Creates a reference variable and a new
                              // object and places a reference to it in a
ArrayList b = a; // Creates a new reference variable and copies the
                 // reference in a to b. They both refer to the same new ArrayList();

b = (ArrayList)a.Clone(); // Clone() creates a new object and copies the
                          // values from a into it, then assigns the reference to b.
                          // a and b now refer to different objects with the same values
```

This is all very simple when working with value types and strings which are immutable. Where it starts to be noticeably different is when you start dealing with members that are reference types.

Instead of assigning strings like you did in the original post, let's create a simple Person class and we'll go through what happens in that scenario.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

ArrayList a = new ArrayList(); // New object, reference in a
a.Add(new Person(){Name = "Jack"}); // New person object, reference added to a.
a.Add(new Person(){Name = "Jill"}); // New person object, reference added to a.

ArrayList b = (ArrayList)a.Clone(); // New ArrayList object created, references 
                                    // to both Person objects are copied to it, 
                                    // then the reference to the new ArrayList 
                                    // is stored in b.
```

At this point, both a and b refer to different ArrayList objects, which have references to the same Person objects. The shallow copy makes a copy of the *value* of each member, and the value is a reference to the Person objects, not the objects themselves.

Because of this, any changes made to one Person object will be reflected in both a and b:

```
Console.WriteLine(((Person)a[0]).Name); // Prints "Jack"
Console.WriteLine(((Person)b[0]).Name); // Prints "Jack"
((Person)a[0]).Name = "Not Jack"; // Changes the value of the object, which is 
                                  // referenced by both a and b.

Console.WriteLine(((Person)a[0]).Name); // Prints "Not Jack"
Console.WriteLine(((Person)b[0]).Name); // Prints "Not Jack"
```

That is how a shallow copy behaves.

A deep copy behaves a bit differently. When you do the shallow copy on the ArrayList, it creates a new ArrayList object and copies over the values from the original. When it's a deep copy, it creates a new ArrayList object just as in the shallow copy, but instead of just coping over the values, it then performs a copy operation on each member recursively.

Here's a simplified explanation of what goes on behind the scenes for a deep copy:

1. Creates a new ArrayList object.
2. Goes through all of the members in the original object and determines if it's a value type or reference type.

   - If it's a value type, it just copies over the value
   - If it's a reference type, start over from step 1 but with this type.

Once that operation is completed, you can now make changes to anything in a or b without affecting the objects in the other ArrayList.